# autofill foreign key automatically (batch spark)

Tags: sql, sql-server, apache-spark, data-modeling

i am trying to understand how can i achieve the following model:

two tables in sql server:

```
 - station table: station_ID (identity PK autoincremented by mssql), name, address, type
```

this table already exists and contains the necessary data

now using spark i want to batch-send data into another table

```
 - business table: date, field1, field2,field3, station_ID (FK references to station table)
```

the data i have in spark is a dataframe containing the following features:

1. date
2. field1
3. field2
4. field3
5. station_name
6. station_address
7. station_type

how can i make spark or MSSQL (IDK) convert automatically the 3 last features to the corresponding Station_ID, is this even doable? am i misunderstanding how data modelling should be?
i would appreciate any kind of help.

Comment: Why not just include the station_id in your dataframe?